# How to use local variables in arrays?

Tags: jsonnet

I want to write a function that returns an array. The array contains objects, where some of them need to reuse a certain object (`metadata` in this example). This object depends on a parameter of the function and repeating it would be a bit cumbersome.

I tried this:

```
local fn(name) = [
    local metadata = { name: name };
    { metadata: metadata, value: "foo" },
    { metadata: metadata, value: "bar" },
];

fn("blub")
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
STATIC ERROR: example.jsonnet:4:17-24: Unknown variable: metadata
```

I would expect that `metadata` is also available within the second item. Is there a way to solve this without repeating `metadata` and without having the function return an object?

Answer (score 3):

When you have `local foo = expr1; expr2`, `foo` is defined only in `expr2`. So in the example you provided `metadata` is visible only in the first element of the array. And local is just an expression. You can use it anywhere in the code where an expression is expected, e.g. `42 + (local x = 17 - 3; x + 4)`. The `local` in Jsonnet is an analog of `let ... in ...` from Haskell/Ocaml etc.

The solution is to define `metadata` for the whole array expression, like in the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51211893/31818).

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that the documentation actually provides [an answer](https://jsonnet.org/learning/tutorial.html#imports) for this:

```
local fn(name) =
    local metadata = { name: name };
    [
        { metadata: metadata, value: "foo" },
        { metadata: metadata, value: "bar" },
    ];

fn("blub")
```